# Доступ объекта к переменной класса

Tags: классы, java

Может ли объект получить доступ к private-переменной класса? Если, да, то каким образом?

Вроде бы, ответ понятен. Объект получает доступ к private-переменной, если эта переменная объявлена в том же классе, к которому принадлежит объект. Каким образом : только через метод. ( как :))

Так? Поправьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Используя рефлексию можно и извне.

Answer (score 3):

Доступ к переменной осуществляется через геттер и сеттер объекта данного класса.

Comment: геттер и сеттер - это методы? допустим public String getName( return Name; } и public void setBonus( double b) { bonus = b; } private double bonus;

Comment: ну да, а ты как "это" называешь?

Comment: через геттер и сеттер... Через любой public метод класса

Comment: А если они в одном пакете, то и через protected метод класса.

Answer (score 3):

1. внутри класса доступ к приватной переменной открыт без ограничений(инфа: модификаторы доступа).
2. доступ вне класса осуществляется через открытые(паблик) методы : геттеры и сеттеры (от анг. get и set).
3. если геттеры и сеттеры отсутствуют - рефлексия(крайне не рекомендуется).
4. Статический вложенный класс имеет полный доступ ко всем членам содержащего его класса, в том числе к членам, объявленным как privat.